# Random int 1-255 to character in C

Tags: c, random, char, int

I have a function that returns an integer, between 1 and 255. Is there a way to turn this int into a character I can `strcmp()` to an existing string.

Basically, I need to create a string of letters (all ASCII values) from a PRNG. I've got everything working minus the int to char part. There's no `Chr()` function like in PHP.

Comment: @Anon. You might want to post that as an answer, so we can vote it up.

Comment: @Matthew, they most likely mean UTF-8.

Comment: Maybe so, but UTF-8 can not be compared using just strcmp.

Comment: Furthermore, UTF-8 supports lots of characters, e.g. all Chinese. There are thousands of those; how are you going to map an integer < 255 to all of those. So UTF-8 isn't what he wants. ISO-8859-x (for 1<=x<=15) would work.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, for "`strcmp()` to an existing string" I don't know *why* you want to compare the char to a string, but, if the string is not one character long, it is not equal to the char. If it is one character long you simply need to do something like this: `if(charA == stringB[0])`. `strcmp` is overkill..

Answer (score 8):

A `char` in C can only take values from `CHAR_MIN` to `CHAR_MAX`.  If `char` is signed, `CHAR_MAX` may be less than 255 (for example, a common value is  127).  If `char` is unsigned, `CHAR_MAX` has to be at least 255.

Assuming your `char` is unsigned, you can just assign the random number to a `char` (in your string for example).  If `char` is signed, you have to be more careful.  In this case, you probably want to assign the value mod 128 to your `char`.

In fact, since you are dealing with ASCII, you may want to do that anyway (ASCII is only up to 127).

Finally, obligatory portability remark: a `char`'s value as an integer may not represent its ASCII value, if the underlying encoding is not ASCII—an example is EBCDIC.

Comment: Alok -- +1 just for that comment :P

Comment: @BillyONeal: Thanks.  3 of my answers got downvoted in a short amount of time - without any explanation.  Sigh.

Answer (score 6):

Just cast it to a `char` (as shown below).  If you're going to use it in a string function (strcat, strcmp, etc), then it has to be in a  char array with a null terminator ('`\0'`) at the end (also shown below)....

```
int num = myrand(1,255);

char str[2] = {(char)num, '\0'};

...

if(strcmp(str, otherString...
```

Answer (score 5):

Just cast it to a char:

```
char c = (char)myRandomInt;
```

Answer (score 4):

A `char` is just an integer with a range of `255` values, and character literals like `'a'` are just a number as well.

Just cast to a char.

```
char C = 67;
char c = 'c';
char zero = 'c' - 'c';
char also_zero = c - 'c';
/*Note: zero == 0*/
```

To use something like `strcmp` you need a `char*` though.  The function expects a pointer to the first element of an array of chars (zero terminated) though and not the address of a single char.

So you want:

```
char szp[] = {c, '\0'};
int isDifferent = strcmp(szp, "c");
```

Comment: `CHAR_MAX` has to be as most 127 if `char` is signed.  Did you mean `zero = C - 'c';`?  `'c' - 'c'` is obviously 0.  But if you did mean `C - 'c';`, then that's not guaranteed by the standard (although in most cases it will be 0).

Comment: @Alok: Whether or not 67 == 'C' doesn't matter for the above answer.   The important part was assigning an integer literal value.  Fixed up wording about signed/unsigned.   Thanks.

Comment: yes.  I was just commenting on your declaration and initialization of `char zero`.

Comment: @Alok: I did mean `'c' - 'c'`, but I added another one `c - 'c'`.  I did not mean C - 'c' because the C is a capital C for 67 in ascii

Answer (score 1):

In C, a `char` is basically an `int` between 0 and 255, so you can treat the integer directly as a char if you want to sprintf to a buffer or similar.  You might want to make your function return a `char`, in fact, to make it obvious what's going on.